# How can I figure out why I see obfuscated methods when profiling Java code?

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

I've been trying to use the Java VisualVM profiler to figure out ways to make my own code more efficient, but I've noticed that a lot of the method calls I see when I try to do CPU sampling on the running process seem to be obfuscated method names. The weird thing is that I don't even know where they're coming from, so I seemingly have no way of knowing how to comprehend what I see.[image]

Comment: Your profiler hopefully comes with alternate views that essentially show you performance in a stack trace. There are plenty of options out there that do. Otherwise your job is going to be really difficult

Comment: Well, I'd assume that someone or something has obfuscated the code. The obvious way to find out what would be to examine your build process.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering how I can find out where these methods are coming from. I've tried decompiling the jars I depend on but it's still not really obvious.